# add articles from multiples html files using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build some site, I have index.html page and I want to load it a section (article section) from another page that stored local in my library

What I have so far is this:

```
  <body>
      </header>
      <main>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="demo">
        <div>
      </div>
   <script src="./scripts/onload.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </header>
  </body>
```

in onload.js I have the code as follow:

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "./first/Prophet-Riddles-App-update.html", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
window.addEventListener("load",loadDoc);
```

so far it's working and it load my Prophet-Riddles-App-update.html to index.html, but want I need is to load multiple file and if I am going in this way, say setup the function twice... it doesn't work.

can anyone please help? what it the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refactor your loader to load file that is given as argument so you will be able to reuse it:

```
function loadDoc(url, target) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById(target).innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function loadAll() {
  loadDoc("./first/Prophet-Riddles-App-update.html", "demo");
  // ... repeat for other pages
}
window.addEventListener("load",loadAll);
```

Comment: If I add more that one html pages it dowsnt work for me,  in  loadAll() I added another page:   loadDoc("./first/Prophet-Riddles-App.html", "demo"); what I am doing wrong?

Comment: it's work! I just was needed to add "+" : document.getElementById(target).innerHTML += this.responseText